# Можно ли использовать несколько предложений во вставках с тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, вставная-конструкция, вставка, точка

Можно ли так написать?

*Считается, что тëмная энергия — она составляет большую часть Вселенной и распределена по всему еë объëму. Она не имеет видимого облика, — влияя на гравитацию, ускоряет расширение Вселенной.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласен с Галиной: так нельзя.
Читаем... видим тире, а значит, после него предложение должно или закончиться, или продолжиться.
*Считается, что тëмная энергия — она составляет большую часть Вселенной и распределена по всему еë объëму.* Это нельзя назвать предложением.

Согласен также с тем, что исходник сто́ит изменить, но, конечно, не так, как в первом ответе, потому что там вставочная информация включена в основной текст, что противоречит замыслу. Предложение могло бы выглядеть так:

*Считается, что тëмная энергия — она составляет большую часть Вселенной, распределена по всему еë объëму и не имеет видимого облика, — влияя на гравитацию, ускоряет расширение Вселенной.*

Но это, по-моему, тоже далеко от идеала.

Если изменений не требуется, то **на основной вопрос** (в шапке) **ответ** следующий.

О нескольких предложениях во вставке, оформленной тире, в правилах не говорится, и это понятно. Достаточно вот этого:

[**Знаки препинания при вставках**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128), **§ 97** (справочник Лопатина)

> Безусловно необходимы скобки при сложной структуре вставки: *Подкараулил этого кота гражданин в тот момент, когда животное с вороватым видом (**что же поделаешь, что у котов такой вид? Это не оттого, что они порочны, а оттого, что они боятся, чтобы кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они — собаки и люди — не причинили им какой-нибудь вред или обиду. И то и другое очень нетрудно, но чести в этом, уверяю, нет никакой. Да, нет никакой!**), да, так с вороватым видом кот собирался устремиться зачем-то в лопухи* (Булг.).

Comment: Ладно, теперь могу согласиться.

Answer (score 2):

Так - категорически нельзя.

*Считается, что тëмная энергия составляет б**о**льшую часть Вселенной и распределена по всему еë объëму. Она не имеет видимого облика; влияя на гравитацию, она ускоряет расширение Вселенной.*

Как вариант.

Но при чём тут "вставки из тире"? Вставка не может состоять из окончания одного предложения (начинающегося со строчной) и через точку нового.

Рискнём так:

*Считается, что тëмная энергия — она составляет большую часть Вселенной и распределена по всему еë объëму — не имеет видимого облика; влияя на гравитацию, она ускоряет расширение Вселенной.*

Можно ещё избавиться от повторяющегося местоимения:

*Считается, что тëмная энергия — она составляет большую часть Вселенной и распределена по всему еë объëму, — не имея видимого облика, влияет на гравитацию и ускоряет расширение Вселенной.*

Comment: То естьнельзя более одного предложения во вставке из тире? Только со скобками так прокатит?

Comment: А где про это написано? Есть ссылка, где говорится, что нельзя более одного предложения во вставке из тире.

Comment: Максимушка, я не знаю, где что написано; я верные знаки расставляю, и даже с вариантами. Тебе зрительно как моя подача?

Comment: Дополнила вариантом: *Считается, что тëмная энергия — она составляет большую часть Вселенной и распределена по всему еë объëму, — не имея видимого облика, влияет на гравитацию и ускоряет расширение Вселенной.*

Comment: Извините, я не просил менять мои предложения. Если так нельзя, то я сам поменяю, как мне надо. Всë, что я просил в вопросе, — это сказать, корректна ли моя запись. Всë остальное — лишнее — то, что я не просил делать (свыше нужного). Почему нельзя так, как в моëм примере? Обосновать нужно, почему так "категорически нельзя".

Comment: А, поняла. Я больше не буду докучать тебе своими ответами. Категоричность объясняется тем, что я редактор.

Comment: И всë-таки, спасибо за ваше мнение. А по поводу изменений предложения: можно было не выключать что-то из вставки, а скобками заменить.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Извините, я не просил менять мои предложения. Если так 
  нельзя, то я сам поменяю, как мне надо. Всë, что я просил 
  в вопросе, — это сказать, корректна ли моя запись. Всë 
  остальное — лишнее — то, что я не просил делать (свыше 
  нужного).
```

А я могу сказать, что дело не только **в скобках и тире,** а в разумности всех этих **экспериментов** с грамматикой.

В предложении **пять сообщений**, зачем их соединять в одно. Чтобы читатель ничего не понял и долго-долго читал его?

Как распределить эти сообщения на **главные** в основной части предложения и **дополнительные** по вставной конструкции? Как из всего этого получить ясный и красиво написанный текст?

А без этих условий все упражнения ничего не стоят. В предложении с **некорректной стилистикой** нельзя правильно расставить знаки.

Поэтому надо было слушать редактора и **спасибо говорить.**